# Gnome mahjongg window drawing error

Tags: gnome

I have been playing Gnome mahjongg for a long time since the installation of Ubuntu. But, recently something happened (which I don't know of), and Mahjongg all of a sudden doesn't draw anything. When I launch Mahjongg, it shows this:
[image]

If I move the window around, the title bar draws weird graphics:
[image]
(I couldn't take a screenshot because just before screenshot is taken, it redraws!)

After launching from the terminal, I got a whole bunch of errors. Errors were too long to paste here, so check [this link](https://pastebin.com/wHjGHq82) for the errors.

I have tried reinstalling, purging and reinstalling, but nothing worked. All other applications are working absolutely fine. Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this?